# Ionic Build Android Error Code 1

Tags: ionic-framework

I created a brand new Ionic starter blank app.  After I added the android platform, I did the "build android" command and receiving this:

"What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException:  Failed to run command:"

With it saying "Error Code 1" and output some java stuff (version 52.0).

The last of it says "Error code 1 for command: cmd with args:  /s /c "c:\users....\app\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug..

Any ideas how to fix it?  I've tried downloading gradle zip and changing it to local, removing and readding android platform, and nothing has worked.

Comment: And if you use the following: `cordova build --release android`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that.  Same errors.